# TypeError: render is not a function. (In 'render(newValue)', 'render' is an instance of Object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-context

```
import{ React, useContext} from 'react';  
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';  
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation ,useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';  
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';  
import { LoginContexts } from '../Contexts/LoginContexts';  


function Screen2() {
  
  const {getEmail} = useContext(LoginContexts);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <LoginContexts.Consumer >
        <Text>{getEmail}</Text>   
      </LoginContexts.Consumer> 
    </View>
  );
}

export default Screen2;
```

**This is my consumer part is which I want to display the text which is present in getEmail in
Text View. please help to solve this problem.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `LoginContexts.Consumer` component expects a render function.

[Context.Consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)

> ```
> <MyContext.Consumer>
>   {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
> </MyContext.Consumer>
> ```

The `useContext` hook ***is*** the consumer, remove the `LoginContexts.Consumer` component.

```
function Screen2() {
  const {getEmail} = useContext(LoginContexts);
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{getEmail}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: After removing this. I get Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @moinmaniar `getEmail` is a verb, which usually indicates it's a function. What are you wanting/trying to render from your context value? If it's relevant, and it sounds like it might be, you may want to include how you create the context and set it's value. Based on those properties it looks like you saved *some* event object into your context state instead of a value (*`event.target.value` perhaps ??*).

Comment: getEmail is my variable. should I change the name of my variable ?

Comment: <LoginContexts.Consumer >
          {value =>{/* what should be written  in order to display value that is present in getEmail ??? */}}
        </LoginContexts.Consumer>

Comment: @moinmaniar "what should be written in order to display value that is present in getEmail" this depends ***entirely*** on what you update this context value to be. If you share how you create a set the context value we can help you render it.

Comment: Actually I know react but new to react native thats why I am facing some problems.<LoginContexts.Consumer >
          {value =>{getEmail}}
        </LoginContexts.Consumer>   This is not giving me an error but my moto is to display the the value which in present in getEmail but my screen goes blank.Please help to solve this issue

Comment: @moinmaniar Well, whether you use the `useContext` hook of the `Context.Consumer` component, the `value` is whatever you are setting the context value to. If you are passing a `getEmail` object value in the context value then it'll be an object value when you access it.

Comment: getEmail is  a state that I created with the help of useState /* const[getEmail, setEmail] = useState(''); */  so, inorder to display the value of state what needs to be done ? any approach ?

Comment: @moinmaniar I guess don't update `getEmail` state to be anything other than a string. Like I said earlier, it looks like you may've accidentally saved the entire event object instead of `event.target.value`.